# On Skew-hermitian and inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is skew-symmetric real under what conditions do we have $(I+A)^{-1} {'}=I-A$ where $'$ stands for transpose?

If $A$ is skew-hermitian complex under what conditions do we have $(I+A)^{-1} {'}=I-A$ where $'$ stands for conjugate transpose?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(I+A)^{-1}{'}=I-A$ is equivalent to $(I+A)^{-1}=(I-A)'=I+A$ since $A$ is skew symmetric. Hence it implies that $(I+A)^2=I$, which gives us $2A+A^2=0$.

The second one is the same.